# Is this a c-default-style? If not, how can i configure it?

Tags: spacemacs, c, cc-mode

I've just started using spacemacs and the docstrings for `cc-styles` are a bit daunting. I've also just started working on a new project in c, and would like to keep consistent with existing style:

```
struct map_s
{
  uint8_t     (*key_hash   )(const void* key);
  bool        (*key_match  )(const void* a, const void* b);
  const void* (*item_key   )(const void* item);
  void        (*item_delete)(void* item);

  map_node_t* base[256];
};
```

My question is, is this a style already implemented as one of the `c-default-style` options? If not, can anyone give me pointers on specifically how to get the `cc-styles` package to add the padding in the function pointer names so that the opening and closing brace are aligned for each member line?

Comment: I don’t believe this behavior is part of cc-mode at all. Automatic formatting usually concerns braces and functions. You will probably have to align these yourself after writing them; after all, how would the mode know how many spaces to add before the next lines existed?  See M-x align.

Comment: i was wondering if someone had already implemented something along these lines; akin to the way tables work in `org-mode`. I will look into align as you suggest.

Comment: It seems that this feature has been missing for a while: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032982/aligning-c-variable-declarations-in-emacs-without-including-chars

Comment: looks like `align` might do what i want. i will post my solution here if i can get it to work.

Comment: maybe something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24472616/3795491

Comment: Did you checked the functions ```M-x cc-guess-xxxx``` in your c file? Tested your code for guessing, seems to be clang with some 4-5 guessed parameters. Can be also installed for you, but maybe a bigger buffer/file would be more close to your needs.

Comment: Great suggestion. Thank you. I will check tonight when i get in.